# gawk: sum from a record to another

Tags: gawk

I have the following table:

```
login:numero:sobrenome:nome   
INICIO    
Alcala:1234:Thomas:Alcala
Baron:1235:Alexis:Baron
Bezier:1236:Pascal:Bezier
Boutier:1237:Damien:Boutier
Buard:1238:Jeremy:Buard
Fagour:1239:Dimitri:Fagour
Fagour:1240:Stephane:Fagour
Justice:1241:Jonathan:Justice
FIM
Numero de usuario = 15
```

I would like to return the sum from line Bezier to Buard.
I tried the following command:

```
gawk '/Bezier/{init=NR}/Buard/{fin=NR}NR>=$init{Sum1+=$2}NR>$fin{Sum2+=$2}END{Sum=Sum1-Sum2;print Sum}BEGIN{FS=":"}' arq_test_awq
```

But no way, Sum2 always begin with /Buard/ line. Even if I put "fin=NR+1", the result is the same. I can begin with /Fagour/ to solve the problem but I just can't understand why it doesn't work with this version.

Answer (score 2):

check whether these are the records of interest

```
$ awk -F: '/Bezier/,/Buard/' file
    Bezier:1236:Pascal:Bezier
    Boutier:1237:Damien:Boutier
    Buard:1238:Jeremy:Buard
```

sum up the second fields and print at the end

```
$ awk -F: '/Bezier/,/Buard/{sum+=$2} END{print sum}' file
3711
```